# Shopify add to cart function only works one at a time and not in a loop

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm creating a way to add all the products in a Shopify collection to the cart as a way to sell bundles.

I have a JavaScript script that determines which level of kit is selected, and loops through each product in the collection. A few products in the bundle we want added more than once, and these are controlled by the tag basicbundleqty:x. So the code loops through the tags for each product, checks for this tag, and if it has it then the qty is set to the suffix of the tag.

```
<script> 

var selected = "not selected";

function kitSelect(){
  selected = document.getElementById('select').value;
  /*if(selected == "not selected"){
    alert('Please select a kit level');
  }
  if(selected == "basic"){
    alert('basic');
  }
  if(selected == "standard"){
    alert('standard');
  }
  if(selected == "pro"){
    alert('pro');
  }*/
} 

function addBundle(){
  var qty = 0;
  if(selected == "basic"){
    {% for kitproduct in collections['Basic-Fixture-Plate-Starter-Kit'].products %}
        qty = 1;
        {% for t in kitproduct.tags %}
            {% if t contains 'basicqty:' %}
                {% assign qty = t | remove: 'basicqty:'%}
                {% assign qty = qty | plus: 0 %}
                qty = {{ qty | json }};
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
          quantity: qty,
         id: {{ kitproduct.variants[0].id }},
        properties: {
        }
      });
    alert(qty);
    {% endfor %}
  } else {
    alert("Please select a kit level first");
  }
  window.location.reload(false);
}
</script>
```

This method *does* work, with one quirk. without the line `alert(qty);` at the end of the for loop, the code does not work. If that alert is not there, the code will seemingly randomly add just one or two of the collection products.

Why does this only work with the `alert()` function, and is there a fix that will allow this to add them all to cart with one click and not require the user clicking through each alert window?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within the asynchronous requests you are sending.

The loop with the alert works because the script stops every time the alert shows up. In the meantime the asynchronous request gets processed.

Shopify explicitly advises against a pattern of adding products in parallel as you can read [here](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-getting-started-using-ajax-api#you-39-re-building-a-quick-order-form-beware).

If you want to add multiple products at once you can add them using one request as described in the shopify documentation:

```
jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
  items: [
    {
      quantity: 1,
      id: 794864229,
      properties: {
        'First name': 'Caroline'
      }
    },
    {
      quantity: 2,
      id: 826203268,
      properties: {
        'First name': 'Mike'
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: This effectively is what I'm doing, this is the code I used to build mine. Would the for loop INSIDE the request fix this, since then it is only making one request and not a new request for each product?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what would fix it.

Comment: You can just build your item list in a loop and send the request after you have collected all items you want to add the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. As [frieder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689500/frieder) pointed out, instead of creating a request for each product in the collection I needed to create a single request and loop through each product inside the request. Here's the working function (minus the quantity check, which I need to add back in):

```
  function addBundle2(){
    jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
      items: [
        {% for kitproduct in collections['Pallets'].products %}
        {
          quantity: 1,
          id: {{ kitproduct.variants[0].id }},
          properties: {
          }
        },
        {% endfor %}
      ]
    });
    window.location.reload(false);
  }
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO, Alex! I think it's relatively bad form to fork & lightly edit an existing answer to your own Q. Why not mark @frieder's as "Accepted", and suggest an edit to it?